# Initializer list and structured bindings deduction ambiguity in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I had always avoided initializations like the following

```
const auto& x = a, y = b;
const int* const x = ptr_1, *const y = ptr_2;  // wot
```

For the reason that the reference and pointer qualifiers don't apply to both the initializations.  Granted it's one of the first things beginners learn, the ambiguity associated with it makes me feel like the following is clearer and requires less thought on the reader's end

```
const auto& x = a;
const auto& y = b;
```

With C++17 and structured bindings I was happy and saw lots of potential.  C++17 outlawed what C++14 and C++11 had failed to fix, `auto x {1}` is an `int` and not `std::initializer_list<int>`.  But why does the following code not work?

```
const auto& [x, y] {a, b};
const auto& [x, y] = {a, b};
```

The latter is in line with the new rules for auto deduction and initializer lists, the expression on the right hand side is treated as an initializer list.  But for the former compilation fails with the following error

```
initializer for variable '[a, b]' with type 'const auto &' contains multiple expressions
```

Is there any way I can declare both x and y with the structured bindings syntax without having to resort to tuples, pairs and the like?  Also why is the former in the code example above ill formed code?  Is there an ambiguity in that syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Structured binding is, so to speak, for "unpacking" things. It's not designed to be a way to combine normal declarations. That `const auto&` applies to neither `a` nor `b`, despite the appearance.

Your particular attempt violates [[dcl.dcl]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#8):

> A *simple-declaration* with an *identifier-list* is called a
> *structured binding declaration* ([dcl.struct.bind]). [...] The *initializer* shall be of the form “`= assignment-expression` ”, of the form “`{ assignment-expression }`”, or
> of the form “`( assignment-expression )`”, where the
> *assignment-expression* is of array or non-union class type.

---

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
const auto bitand <:x, y:> = std::tie(a, b);
```

This structured binding declaration is (very) roughly equivalent to

```
const auto bitand __e = std::tie(a, b); // hidden variable
auto and x = std::get<0>(__e);
auto and y = std::get<1>(__e);
```

(The real thing uses `tuple_element`, not `auto`.)

Notes:

- The `const auto bitand` applies to *the hidden variable* and only the hidden variable. `x` and `y` are always references even if you write just `auto`; whether their referent is `const` depends on the `const` propagation properties of the initializer's type.
- A temporary materialized from a prvalue initializer will have its lifetime extended by the reference binding.
- In this example, both `x` and `y` are of type "reference to int"; it is valid to write `x = 1;`.
- There's special treatment for structured bindings in the `decltype` wording.

These semantics are unsurprising if we are talking about unpacking a struct, etc., with two "reference to int" members; a `const` on such things doesn't actually affect the referent's constness. OTOH, you are in for a bad surprise if you want to use structured binding declarations for something they aren't designed to do.

Comment: Why would the types of `x` and `y` be `int&` and not `const int&`?  the type of `__e` is `const std::tuple<int&, int&>&`, so calling `std::get<>` on that should return a const reference type right?

Comment: And according to your example `x` and `y` will always be reference types, but in this example here they are not https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dligcds69j04EwY0

Comment: @Curious `decltype` handles structure bindings specially.

Comment: @Curious Of course if you `tie` two `const int`s you get a `tuple<const int &, const int&>`. /sigh

Comment: I said that because in your example the types of `x` and `y` are non const `int&`

Comment: @Curious And your point is...? Actually, don't answer that. I'm done here.

Comment: Did you replace `&` and `&&` by multigraphs on purpose?

Comment: Your standard quote has curly braces twice and missing the `=` token case instead.  (And yeah, what the heck with the digraphs and english tokens??)

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is just not supported.  You can only unpack aggregate classes and objects which for which `std::get` has been overloaded: https://skebanga.github.io/structured-bindings/

Unfortunately, you cannot really make use of the cool deduction guide because you want a reference to `a` and not to the tuple member.  Thus you have to write out the template parameter list.

```
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  const auto& [x, y] = std::tuple<int&,int&>{a, b};
}
```

You could also not be as stupid as me and read the docs correctly.

```
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  const auto& [x, y] = std::forward_as_tuple(a, b);
}
```

`const auto& [x, y] = std::tie(a, b);` works as well.

Comment: That `const auto&` is horrendously misleading. Try writing `x = 1;`.

Comment: @T.C. Interesting.  Any idea why `const` is ignored here?

Comment: @HenriMenke its because if you make a `std::tuple<int&, int&>` and then call `std::get<>` on that the `const` does not propagate to the value pointed to the reference.  It's the same issue as a `const` when applied to a pointer not propagating to the actual value but only to the pointer itself.

Comment: `You can only unpack struct and tuple` is just completely wrong. You can (also) unpack anything for which there is a specialisation of `std::get()`. Raw arrays, user-defined types with bizarre semantics, doesn't matter.

Comment: @underscore_d This is what https://skebanga.github.io/structured-bindings/ suggested.  I didn't read the whole proposal.  I edited my answer to reflect your improvement.

Comment: @HenriMenke Now it's still wrong, but in a different way. :P Having `std::get()` is not the _only_ way to support decomposition by structured bindings. As you originally mentioned, aggregate classes are innately supported. To that I added, although not very clearly by saying "You can (also) unpack", anything supporting `std::get()`. Glancing over some summaries, I think I might've been wrong about raw i.e. C-style arrays being supported, though: it might only be `std::array` with its `get()`.